# Unable to find the PillarGrid namespace in Ocean 2013?

Tags: ocean

I am trying to upgrade my plug-in from Petrel 2012 to Petrel 2013 but it seems that they have removed the `PillarGrid` class from the `DomainObject` namespace in 2013.

Where can I find the `PillarGrid` class in 2013?

Comment: I found it. It seems that the Petrel.DomainObject assembly has been removed and a Petrel.modeling assembly is added in the 2013 version

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The namespaces have been split into different assemblies. Here is how you find the name of the assembly:

1. Open the Ocean documentation (chm);
2. Find the class/domain object you work with, e.g. Grid in Slb.Ocean.Petrel.DomainObject.PillarGrid namespace;
3. Scroll down to the very end of the Grid class. here you find the reference:
   Example:

> Ocean Petrel 2013.1  Copyright (c) Schlumberger 2006-2013. All rights
>   reserved.
>   Assembly: Slb.Ocean.Petrel.Modeling (Module:
>   **Slb.Ocean.Petrel.Modeling**) Version: 13.1.0.0 (13.1.0.0)